# Visualforce to output result of Javascript function as application/json content

Tags: visualforce, json, contenttype

I am using a Javascript library to process some JSON data in Visualforce. The result of this operation should become the output of the VF page (`ContentType=application/json`). I know this is easily doable with an Apex controller providing the content of the page, but here there's no Apex. Just pure Javascript.

```
<apex:page contentType="application/json" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jslib}"/>

    <script>
        // do client-side processing using jslib
        // output resulting JSON content on VF page
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Obviously, the above markup doesn't work but hopefully it demonstrates what I'm trying to do. Ultimately I want to get the resulting JSON value from Apex using `Page.MyVfPage.getContent().toString()`.

Comment: all you want to do is write the JSON object to the screen?

Comment: i don't think you can with `getContent()` if waiting on the JS to execute on the page. i know from working with `getContentAsPdf()` this surely has never worked.

Comment: @Ronnie Come to think of it, you're right. I don't know why I thought this might possibly work. Feel free to post an answer and I'll mark as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `getContent()` will not work as this does not allow for JavaScript to execute. When using `PageReference.getContent()` methods this will pull the content of the Visualforce page as it is loaded. it will not await for additional methods or custom JavaScript code to execute. Using `getContent` or `getContentAsPdf` will pull in the HTML template and any relevant data at the end of construction of the layout. The method always will return a `Blob` of what is rendered at that time. Any custom page level javascript or dynamically | lazy loaded styles will not come in if they are not present at the time that this execution completes its initial render.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I have, and this was what he asked for.

Comment: Thanks @Ronnie ! Can you expand a bit more on that answer so it is helpful. Like why one cannot use getContent(). The answer is too short i feel. Any more explanation would be value add.